# SwiftUI UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true just on one View

Tags: swift, swiftui

How can i turn Sleep off when just one View is Appeared ?

`UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true` stop the screen from going to sleep on every View.

how just in ContentView ?

```
struct ContentView: View {
  UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true


}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `onAppear` and `onDisappear`:

```swift
var body: some View {
    Text("Hi there")
        .onAppear { UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true }
        .onDisappear { UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = false }
}
```